# Check status of past transaction using cli

Tags: cardano-cli, transaction, cardano-serialization-lib

How can you check the status of a past transaction given the TxHash (i.e. pending, failed, or successful) and also the assurance level / number of confirmations and block number? (like on Cardanoscan here for example [https://cardanoscan.io/transaction/df8c580d50c1b8f97bd0831edb622be2737bc2a7e46971a8b369ab12e51cb214#:~:text=7214272-,Assurance,-Low](https://cardanoscan.io/transaction/df8c580d50c1b8f97bd0831edb622be2737bc2a7e46971a8b369ab12e51cb214#:%7E:text=7214272-,Assurance,-Low)?

Is this possible using the cli or @emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-asmjs library?

Answer (score 4):

The main option you have with `cardano-cli` is to keep running

```
cardano-cli query utxo --tx-in df8c580d50c1b8f97bd0831edb622be2737bc2a7e46971a8b369ab12e51cb214#0 --mainnet
```

Where `df8c580d50c1b8f97bd0831edb622be2737bc2a7e46971a8b369ab12e51cb214` is the TxHash and `#0` indicates the first output of that transaction, noting that all transactions must have at least one output.

It will give an output like the following

```
 TxHash                                 TxIx        Amount
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
df8c580d50c1b8f97bd0831edb622be2737bc2a7e46971a8b369ab12e51cb214     0        49517208 lovelace + 1 7482551a1dab4a992e579718a81e6cd14401bf4d02856c0c738a2587.5061706572536f63696574793032303132 + 1 7482551a1dab4a992e579718a81e6cd14401bf4d02856c0c738a2587.5061706572536f63696574793036333930 + TxOutDatumNone
```

Note it will only highlight the moment the transaction makes it to a block accepted by your local node with no additional details such as the block number or assurance level.

As it currently stands there are limited options to query the status of a transaction using the `cardano-cli`. `cardano-serialization-lib-asmjs` on the other hand has no querying capability but allows you to build and serialise the transaction itself.

For more information you will have to consume the following resources from HTTP-based APIs

- [Blockfrost](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Transactions/paths/%7E1txs%7E1%7Bhash%7D/get)
- [Koios](https://api.koios.rest/#post-/tx_info)

These will give you the block number but you will have to calculate the assurance level yourself by subtracting it from the current tip.